# Saving a matrix in the text by using different spacing in the columns

Tags: pandas, text

I have two matrices; one that shows data and another which shows information about data.
matrix data:

```
         10        0         1         2         3         4         5   
0    1979001  0.439353  0.255700  0.270974  0.346030  0.239454  0.229373   
1    1979002  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
2    1979003  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
3    1979004  0.109838  0.063925  0.067743  0.086508  0.059863  0.057343   
4    1979005  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
5    1979006  5.609492  4.596672  4.773364  5.357853  4.617296  4.391231   
6    1979007  1.311139  1.003951  1.077528  1.384126  0.991775  0.921057   
7    1979008  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
8    1979009  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
9    1979010  0.140775  0.158411  0.140194  0.107244  0.133659  0.167177   
10   1979011  1.029793  1.311986  1.289152  1.057077  1.381493  1.350875   
11   1979012  2.229281  1.592264  1.786475  2.479978  1.640830  1.411289   
12   1979013  2.094382  1.370128  1.531622  2.126227  1.384526  1.200632   
13   1979014  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000  0.000000   
14   1979015  0.439353  0.255700  0.270974  0.346030  0.239454  0.229373
```

and matrix information in blow:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWKaU.png)

```
            0     1     2     3     4     5 
Station  sub1  sub2  sub3  sub4  sub5  sub6 

Lati        2   5.3   4.6     3     5     6  

Long      0.2   0.2   0.3   0.8   0.7   0.6   

Elev     1000  1000  1000  1000  1000  1000
```

I want with the tow matrix (sown above) to save the one text file following format, the first column of the first row in the text (that is, the matrix of information) is spaced from the other columns, and the first row after the columns is separated by (,) .
I also want to write the data matrix without a patch (in the form of a sample) under the information matrix.
I tried to do this with different codes and using .csv_to and mode (a), which unfortunately did not.please help me.
thanks

text file sample

```
Station  1,2,3,4,5

Lati    36.8 36.8 36.7 36.7 36.7

Long    45.7 45.6 45.6 45.6 45.6

Elev    1000 1000 1000 1000 1000

1979001000.0000.1000.1000.0-99.0

1979002000.7000.6000.3000.2000.0

1979003000.0000.0-99.0000.0000.0

1979004005.3011.0015.0015.8016.9

1979005000.2001.2002.3002.7003.0
```

-99.0 and 000.1 are two of the above text files

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWKaU.png)